# practise making logical class diagrams

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I'm looking for practise cases for practising making class diagrams. I'm familiar with UML notation and how the construct class diagrams, but often fail at making it redundant and logical.

A quick search didnt get me anything, so i'm hoping i could find an answer here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look up CRC card technique for a start. Also it depends on your usecase(s) so the discussion is best based on a concrete scenario that you might want to add to your question.

Comment: Thanks! looks like a great technique. I'm kind off looking for scenario's to work out a diagram for (with the right solutions provided), so i can reflect on what i'm doing wrong.